# On a bounded linear Operator, $C^{\infty}$ functions and the Fréchet derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm taking a graduate engineering class about optimization methods where we have been talking about some things from analysis. This one about the Fréchet derivative has me confused:

Given two normed spaces $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ then $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow  \mathcal{Y}$ is differentiable if there is a bounded linear mapping $\mathcal{A}:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{||f(x+z)-f(x) -\mathcal (A)z ||}{||z||_y}=0
\end{equation}
holds.

The bounded part of the linear mapping is what confuses me. We have been given this counter example of a bounded linear mapping.

Consider $\mathcal{X}$ as the space of $C^{\infty}$ functions on an open interval with the $L_{\infty}$ norm. Consider the linear mapping: $\frac{d}{dt}:C^{\infty}\rightarrow C^{\infty}$ and the function $h_k(t)=\sin(kt)$
Then 
\begin{equation}
||\frac{d}{dt} h_k(t)||_{\infty}=|k|\cdot ||\cos (kt)||_{\infty}=|k|
\end{equation}
But $||\sin(kt)||_{\infty}=1$ which implies that there is a not constant $c$ such that $||\frac{d}{dt} h_k(t)||_{\infty}\leq |c|\cdot||\sin(kt)||\text{ } \forall\text{   } k$. Thus, $\frac{d}{dt}$ is not a bounded linear operator.

There are a couple things I don't understand about this:

- First, it seems like circular reasoning to take the derivative to find out if it's differentiable according the above definition.
- Second my professor says the derivative is still $\cos(kt)$ which has left me incredibly confused. If $\sin(kt)$ still has a derivative, then what does the definition above actually mean?

I would really appreciate some insight into this and/or a pointer some good resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little confusing as presented. Hopefully this will not confuse more...

The operator is defined in terms of an ordinary derivative which is the source
of confusion. The question is whether or not the operator has a Fréchet
derivative.

First, note that if $f$ is a bounded linear operator, then the Fréchet derivative is just $f$ itself since $f(x+h) = f(x)+f(h)$, and $f$ is bounded.

Now consider the space given in the question, and define
$f(x) = \dot{x}$ (that is, $f(x)(t)$ is just the ordinary 'time' derivative of $x$ evaluated at $t$). It is easy to see that $f$ is linear, so $f$ will have a
Fréchet derivative **iff** $f$ is bounded.

Since $f$ is not bounded, it does not have a Fréchet derivative.

That is, the ordinary derivative operator does not have a Fréchet derivative (on the given space).

Note the difference between $f$ having a Fréchet derivative and just evaluating
$f$ on a particular function (where, in this case, evaluation happens to mean
'take the ordinary derivative'). So we have
$f(t \mapsto \sin (kt)) = t \mapsto k\cos (kt)$, but $f$ itself does
not have a Fréchet derivative.

Aside: When dealing with functions defined on finite dimensional spaces, all linear operators are bounded, so this issue does not arise and the usual concern is just showing the existence of the linear operator.

Comment: Thanks I think that makes some sense. I guess I didn't realize that the ordinary derivative operator is distinct from the Frechet derivitive. I will have to read about this more.

Comment: Well, the ordinary derivative is a Fréchet derivative, but there is a difference between differentiating a function and differentiating the differentiation operator. Since the ordinary derivative arises on finite dimensional spaces, there is no need to specify the bounded part.

Comment: Here is another example that may help. Consider the space $L^\infty$ which includes non differentiable functions. The function $f(x)(t) = x(t)+1$ is an operator on $L^\infty$ and it is easy to see that $f$ has a Fréchet derivative (the identity operator).

Answer (score 1):

The map, $F:C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\to C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), f\mapsto \frac{df}{dx}$ is an operator on the space $C^{\infty}$. (We can take $||\cdot||=||\cdot||_{\infty}$)

We now want to take derivative of this operator $F$.

Should such a Fréchet derivative exist, we have that

$$\lim_{||h||\to 0}\frac{||F(f+h)-F(f)-D_F(h)||}{||h||}$$

exists for some bounded linear operator $D_F$. This operator $D_F$ is map from $C^{\infty}\to C^{\infty}$ and it depends on $F$ but also on where you take the derivative (in this case what $f$ is).

In the finite dimensional case, a linear operator is automatically a bounded operator as well but this is not the case for infinite dimensional spaces such as $C^{\infty}$. Here the limit approaches $0$ in all sorts of directions,

Actually, in this particular, case $F$ is a linear operator (in general, the thing that we are taking Fréchet derivative need not even be linear.)

We can therefore use $F(f+h)-F(f)=F(h)$ to realise that should such a Fréchet derivative exist, it needs to be $D_F=F$ (In other words, our Fréchet derivative actually doesn't depend on the location of where we take the derivative in this case.)

The problem is that $D_F=F$ is a linear operator but it is not bounded.

As you said if $f(x)=\sin(nx)$ then, $||f||=1$ but $||F(f)||=||n\cos nx||=n$. So $||F||_{op}=\sup_{||f||=1}\frac{||F(f)||}{||f||}=\infty$